# AX 2009 / 2012 CS database collation

Tags: axapta, collation, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I've found several articles, posts and threads that case sensitive database collation isn't supported. Neither by 2009 nor by 2012. In Installation-progress, you'll be faced with this, latest. But I wasn't able to find a concrete reason for that behaviour.

So - what's the reason, CS collation isn't allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparisons are case insensitive in X++. Using a case sensitive database on a case insensitive programming environment would be strange indeed.

Example: transactions may be created with currencies "usd" or "USD". Different currencies?

Comment: So internal and / or default string comparisons are CI, right? Since [strCmp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa672979%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) is not.

Comment: `strCmp` is the exception, as it exposes the C function directly. Comparisons ==, !=, etc. are case insensitive.